# substring does not work with jquery .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

My code:

```
monthName = $("#StartDateMonth option:selected").text();
console.log(monthName, monthName.substring(0,3), 'December'.substring(0,3));
```

Return:

```
December
<nothing>
Dec
```

Why this ridiculous thing occur?
My browser: Chrome - Ubuntu

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Try `monthName= monthName.toString();` in between those two lines of code.

Comment: is monthName a Date Object?

Comment: Try `$.trim(monthName).substring(0,3)`

Comment: I tried `monthName.toString();`, `String(monthName);` and `monthName + ""` too. Still the same result. I printed out type of monthName also and it return `String`. After tried $.trim, it work! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: +1 for the stupid and pointless -1.

Comment: @OneOfOne You're right! Thank for driving me the right way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be the spaces in the result of `.text()`. You can trim it before calling `substring`.

Example:

```
monthName = $.trim($("#StartDateMonth option:selected").text());
console.log(monthName, monthName.substring(0,3), 'December'.substring(0,3));
```